# Is there any performance overhead if I use a lot of <%@ Register directives on markup?

Tags: asp.net, performance, directive, page-directives

Some of my pages have a lot of <%@ Register directives for controls that are no longer used neither on markup nor dynamically created.

I'm wondering if I would benefit or gain some performance if I bother on removing all those directives from all pages. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be some overhead from parsing the directives (especially on first load as the temporary classes are generated), though as you do not use the controls this would be minor.

This is something you can test for yourself.